# How to Integrate MySQL Database with Jenkins

Tags: mysql, jenkins, syntax, jenkins-pipeline

I'm on the Jenkins ver. 2.176.1.

I wish to connect to mysql database by passing host, port, and credentials in Jenkins pipeline for Select / Insert queries to an existing database table.

As, I have understood there is no good plugin that works for MySQL connectivity (tried a couple which do not mask the password) I decided to set the MySQL hostname and Port as environment variables and username and password as credentials in Jenkins.

I have three plugins installed for this purpose viz.
Credentials plugin, Credentials Binding plugin,Plain Credentials plugin

[image: Jenkins Credential Plugins]

[image: Jenkins Credential Plugins]

I then setup mysql credentials by clicking: Jenkins->Credentials->System->Global credentials (unrestricted)

[image: Mysql credentials]

Now inorder to generate code for pipeline for accessing these credentials i go to-> http:///pipeline-syntax/ see below snapshot:
[image: Syntax Generator]

Below are two issues I'm seeking solution for.

1. The credentials dropdown in the pipeline syntax generator does not work. I was expecting the mysql credentials ID to show up in the drop-down as expected. Can you suggest what could be the issue here ?
2. I need the syntax to pass the MySQL username and password as variables to a different Jenkins job from my pipeline script.

> ```
> steps 
>     {
> build job: 'myjob1', parameters: [string(name: 'Region', value: "${params.Region}"),<mysql-username>,<mysql-password>)]
>     }
> ```

Can you please help me with the same ?

Comment: looks like very few or no jenkins experts here :)

Comment: you can't directly connect to the Database - use database plugin and install other plugin for the connection. @see https://plugins.jenkins.io/database